# Metalic sound from generated sound with sin()

Tags: c++, linux, audio, trigonometry

I have the following code, a mix of [different sources](http://joshparnell.com/blog/2013/03/21/how-to-write-a-wav-file-in-c/) since I'm learning C++ from C and PHP background:

```
int main() {
  const unsigned int sampleRate = 48000;
  // prepare a 6 seconds buffer and write it
  const unsigned long int size = sampleRate*6;
  float sample[size];
  unsigned long int i = 0;
  unsigned long insin, insinb, factor;

  // Multiply for 2*pi and divide by sampleRate to make the default period of 1s
  // So the freq can be stated in Hz
  factor = 2*3.141592;

  for (i; i<size; i++) {
    // Store the value of the sin wave
    insin = 440*float(i)*factor/float(sampleRate);
    insinb = 880*float(i)*factor/float(sampleRate);

    if (i > size/8)
      // Attempt to make it sound more instrument-like
      sample[i] = 0.7 * sin(insin) + 0.3 * sin(insinb);
    else
      sample[i] = 0.7 * sin(insinb) + 0.3 * sin(insin);

    // DEBUG
    if (i < 1000)
      printf("%f\n", sample[i]);
    }

  writeWAVData("sin.mp3", sample, size, sampleRate, 1);
  return 1;
  }
```

It creates the .mp3 file. However, it's always 1 second long and it has a really metallic sound. From the `// DEBUG`, I retrieve the values, which are not really sine-like. A small portion:

```
0.637161
0.637161
0.637161
0.070853
0.070853
0.070853
0.070853
0.070853
0.070853
0.070853
0.070853
0.070853
-0.383386
-0.383386
-0.383386
-0.383386
-0.383386
```

I think the metallic sound might come from the fact that the sin() returned values are too square-like. Why could this be? **Can I get sin() to return a "better quality" function, or am I doing something else inherently wrong?** In case you have any interest, here's the beginning and the rest of the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sndfile.hh>

template <typename T>
void write(std::ofstream& stream, const T& t) {
  stream.write((const char*)&t, sizeof(T));
  }

template <typename SampleType>
void writeWAVData(const char* outFile, SampleType* buf, size_t bufSize,
                  int sampleRate, short channels)
  {
  std::ofstream stream(outFile, std::ios::binary);
  stream.write("RIFF", 4);
  write<int>(stream, 36 + bufSize);
  stream.write("WAVE", 4);
  stream.write("fmt ", 4);
  write<int>(stream, 16);
  write<short>(stream, 1);                                        // Format (1 = PCM)
  write<short>(stream, channels);                                 // Channels
  write<int>(stream, sampleRate);                                 // Sample Rate
  write<int>(stream, sampleRate * channels * sizeof(SampleType)); // Byterate
  write<short>(stream, channels * sizeof(SampleType));            // Frame size
  write<short>(stream, 8 * sizeof(SampleType));                   // Bits per sample
  stream.write("data", 4);
  stream.write((const char*)&bufSize, 4);
  stream.write((const char*)buf, bufSize);
  }
```

And I compile it simply by doing this in Linux (Ubuntu 13.10):

```
 g++ audio.cpp -o audio && ./audio
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be:

```
unsigned long insin, insinb, factor;
```

These are integer types.

try changing this to

```
float insin, insinb, factor;
```

Comment: Indeed that was it. Thank you so much.